# setxkbmap switches between 2 out of 3 layouts

Tags: x11, gentoo, keyboard-layout, xkb

Issuing that command:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,ua,ru" -variant ",winkeys" -option "grp:shift_caps_toggle,grp_led:scroll" -model pc105 -rules xorg
```

When hitting <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> I'm switching between English (us) and Ukrainian (ua) layouts, but not Russian (ru).

I've tried to reset it with the following command:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,ua,ru" -option ""
```

and played with many different options - nothing helps.

My system is Gentoo Linux and window manager wmii.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your command (I had to add "-keycodes evdev" to handle my arrow keys, but that is irrelevant), and I could cycle trough the three layouts.

Could it be that Caps+Shift is intercepted by the window manager ?

You can also issue the command: `xkbcomp $DISPLAY somefile.txt`(or `xkbcomp $DISPLAY - | less`) and look that CAPS is defined like this:

```
key <CAPS> {         [       Caps_Lock,  ISO_Next_Group ] };
```

look if the dump of xkbcomp changes when you change the keyboard layout with Caps+Shift (it should not!)

Comment: Confirmed:
key <CAPS> {         [       Caps_Lock,  ISO_Next_Group ] };

My window manager is wmii which is very lightweight. I doubt it intercept anything.

Comment: It may still be that wmii does something about the caps lock modifier. Try editing the dump file to change CAPS definition to send something else, for exemple letter "a", instead of ISO_Next_Group, and load it with `xkbcomp thedumpfile $DISPLAY` and see if Shift+CapsLock on a terminal types an "a".

Answer (score 0):

`setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ua,ru -variant ,winkeys -option grp:lwin_switch,grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:caps`

On <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> hit it switches between all three.
On <kbd>WIN</kbd> press-and-hold it will turn on next one to current, e.g.: if you current layout 'ua' it will type in 'ru'